# Accessing attributes within an xml element in java

Tags: java, xml

We have a directory that returns search results as an XML document.

```
<directory.person>
   <person netid="" pidm="" student="" affiliate="">
      <picture>no</picture>
      <name>...</name>
   </person>
```

I'm trying to parse and read it in java using the following code:

```
    try{  
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();                                         
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");

        for(int i = 0;i < nodes.getLength(); i++){  
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            NodeList pidm = element.getElementsByTagName("@pidm");
            Element line = (Element)pidm.item(0);
            value = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
            if(value.compareTo("Dana")==0 || value=="Dana")
                out.println(value);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is with actually accessing that pidm variable in the second line of my "for" loop. I'm not sure how to do that. Basically, I need to output by pidm because that's the unique identifier for each person returned. I know that jstl would be easier, but the people over this don't want to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Element` object in the first line of the loop should already be the `<person />` element. So you should be able to grab the attribute by:

```
for(int i = 0;i < nodes.getLength(); i++){  
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

    // retrieve the attribute, then get the value
    Attr pidm = element.getAttributeNode("pidm");
    String pidmString = pidm.getValue();

    // or get the attribute directly
    String pidmDirectString = element.getAttribute("pidm");

    ... // the rest of your code
}
```

See [Element Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)

Comment: Great! That worked. I was looking at the API documentation but I most have overlooked that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The class `org.w3c.dom.Element` has a number of methods to access element attributes.

The simplest case here would be to invoke `element.getAttribute("pidm");`.

It will get you the **value** for a given attribute.

Otherwise you can browse the other `getAttribute...` methods of `Element`, to your convenience.

API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
for(int i = 0;i < nodes.getLength(); i++){  
  Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
  value = elem.getAttributeValue("pidm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, the "pidm" is an attribute.  If you need to get that, use element.getAttribute("pidm");